# Asking for proof for total voltage is equal to the sum of the voltages of the resistors (connected at series pattern)

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

Recently I was taught that when a set of resistors are connected as a series pattern the total voltage of the resistors is equal to the sum of the voltages of each resistor. I know how to prove this using Equilibrium resistance (Refer to the below image)

[image]

We know that the current (I is constant across the circuit)
And also we know that the total resistance in the circuit is equal to $R_{eq}=R_{1}+R_{2}+R_{3}$

So with $V=IR$

$V=I(R_{1}+R_{2}+R_{3})$

$V=IR_{1}+IR_{2}+IR_{3}$

So this means the total voltage is equal to the sum of the voltages of the resistors

But the problem is when deriving the formula Equilibrium resistance I used the fact that the total voltage is equal to the sum of the voltages of the resistors.

So is there anyone who can prove that the total voltage is equal to the sum of the voltages of the resistors without using the Equilibrium resistance or proving the total resistance of resistors connected as series is equal to the sum of the resistance of each resistor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's label the points where potential is measured by the voltmeters: $A$ is measured by the left wires of $V_1$ and $V$, $B$ is measured by the right wire of $V_1$ and the left wire of $V_2$, $C$ is measured by right wire of $V_2$ and the left wire of $V_3$, and $D$ is measured by the right wires of $V_3$ and $V$. Let's label the potentials at these points as $U_A$, $U_B$, $U_C$, and $U_D$. The potential differences measured by the voltmeters are
$$V_1 = U_A - U_B$$
$$V_2 = U_B - U_C$$
$$V_3 = U_C - U_D$$
$$V = U_A - U_D$$
The sum of the individual potential differences is
\begin{aligned}
V_1 + V_2 + V_3 &= (U_A - U_B) + (U_B - U_C) + (U_C - U_D) \\
                &= U_A - U_B + U_B - U_C + U_C - U_D \\
                &= U_A - U_D \\
                &= V
\end{aligned}

Comment: thank you for your effort